# Holding the constraints of a constrained optimization when transformed into unconstrained optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization, constraints

Suppose there is a constrained convex optimization problem as shown below

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \min\limits_{\mathbf{x}}
& & f(\mathbf{x}) \\
& \text{s.t.}
& & g(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{c} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Using methods such as Augmented Lagrangian method it can be rewritten to a unconstrained convex optimization problem as

$$
\min\limits_{\mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}) -\mathbf{y}^T(g(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{c})+\frac{\rho_y}{2}||g(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{c}||^2_2
$$

where $\mathbf{y}$ is the Lagrange multiplier and $\rho_y$ is the weight for the penalty term.

When solving this unconstrained convex optimization problem, the result wanted is $g(\mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{c}$ as close to zero as possible (this constraint must hold) while minimizing $f(\mathbf{x})$, however the solver is not afraid of making the term  $-\mathbf{y}^T(g(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{c})+\frac{\rho_y}{2}||g(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{c}||^2_2$ larger as long as it can bring $f(\mathbf{x})$ down and minimize the overall cost, and the resulted $\mathbf{x}$ is not usable since the hard constraint $g(\mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{c}$ is broken.

What is the right way to overcome this problem?

Comment: You've got a conceptual error here. The Augmented Lagrangian method does not "rewrite" the problem into an unconstrained optimization problem. Rather, it transforms it into an entire *family* of such problems, parameterized by the value of the Lagrange multiplier $y$. The correct application of the Augmented Lagrangian method depends critically on the periodic update of this value $y$.

Comment: So in other words, you're not done after you've solved that first unconstrained problem, not by a longshot.

Comment: It is solved iteratively by, finding the normal equation with respect to $x$ (assuming f and g is differentiable), update $y$ by $y=y-\rho_y(g(x) - c)$, rinse and repeat a fix amount of iterations or till it converges. So $y$ is definitely not fixed all the way.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MichaelGrant After solving it this way, the problem I described still exist, what is your suggestion to overcome it?

Comment: I am not sure what to tell you. How sure are you that the problem is convex? For instance, what is $g$?

Comment: Pretty sure it's convex. For instance, my original problem actually have 2 variable $x_1$ and $x_2$ to minimize, and g is $x_1+x_2=1$

Comment: Then AL is absolute overkill. Just eliminate one of the variables. Assuming it is just a toy problem designed to experiment with the AL method, though, I still don't have an answer.